# Synonymize [light] with [lighting]

Tags: discussion, tags

[lighting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting) has 290 questions. [light](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light) has 35 questions and no tag wiki or excerpt. It appears to cover the same things as [lighting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lighting). Should they be synonymized?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion, these tags are pretty much identical, as one describes the act and the other the object. They cover the same concept and could easily be merged together.

Comment: Agreed. Merging now.... Done.